# jquery request every 30 seconds to check if file exist

Tags: jquery

i am uploading a file to my apache server which sends its off to another server for heavy computation which takes about 10 minutes to finish.

i am looking for a code maybe in jQuery which can help me keep the connection active between the client and the server by sending requests every 30 secs while the 3rd server is performing the request.

i read somewhere i can user setInterval to check for file exist but how do i make it stop once the output file is ready to be sent back to the client.

below is my html and js code

```
echo "<form name=\"cre\" id=\"cre\" action=\"#\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">";
echo "<label for=\"file\">Filename: </label>";
echo "<input type=\"file\" name=\"file\" id=\"file\" ><br><br>";
echo "<label for=\"email\">Email: </label>";
echo "<input id=\"email\" type=\"text\" name=\"email\" maxlength=\"40\"><br><br>";  
echo "<input type=\"submit\" onclick=\"return validate();\" id=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo "</form>";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<div id=\"uploader\"></div>";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<div id=\"outdata\">";
echo "</div>";


function keepalive(){
    var feedback = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "keepalive.php",
               }).success().responseText;
    $('#outdata').html(feedback);
}

function validate() 
{
    var file = $("#file").val();
    if(!file || file == '' || file == null)
    {
        document.getElementById("outdata").innerHTML="Please select a file";
        return false;
    }   
    var options = {
          target: '#outdata',
          url:'process.php', 
          data:{
             accesstype:"cre"
          },
          beforeSubmit: function() {
             $('#uploader').html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
             $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
          },
          success:  function() {
              $('#uploader').html('');
              clearInterval(sI);
              $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
          }
     };
     $('#cre').ajaxSubmit(options);
     var sI = setInterval(keepalive(), 30000);  
     return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the script is not able to reference  `sI` from where you are calling
clearInterval(sI); so you can make sI as a global variable . so declare sI as `var sI=null` at the top.

May be this is what you wanted.

```
var sI = setInterval(keepalive(), 30000); //place this here 

function validate() 
{
    var file = $("#file").val();
    if(!file || file == '' || file == null)
    {
        document.getElementById("outdata").innerHTML="Please select a file";
        return false;
    }   
    var options = {
          target: '#outdata',
          url:'process.php', 
          data:{
             accesstype:"cre"
          },
          beforeSubmit: function() {
             $('#uploader').html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
             $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
          },
          success:  function() {
              $('#uploader').html('');
              clearInterval(sI);//on success kill the set interval 
              $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
          }
     };
     $('#cre').ajaxSubmit(options);
     return false;   
}
```

Comment: i placed an alert within keepalive to see if it runs every 30 seconds. i noticed it is only being executed once. is there something wrong with the code ?

Comment: after the first success of ajax you are killing it

Comment: Thanks for the reply Arun. i have a followup question. when my file is uploaded to the webserver, it sends it to another server that takes about 12 minutes to do some heavy computation. once the processing is finished, it sends the file back via email. The problem is if a small file is uploaded i can see the responseText in the browser saying the mail was successfully sent, however, when the server runs for about 12 minutes the browser never receives a response and only shows the processing.gif whereas the server has actually finished processing the file and already emailed it back to the user

Comment: First of all 12 mins is along time for a user to wait. you have to check the maximum execution time of your server side language .if possible execute the long processing as a background process.